# C++ template pack for function argument

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to create a template function which receives a variadic parameter pack of function pointers?

```
template<ReturnType (*FN)(), ReturnType (*FNX...)()>
void run() {
  ...
  run<FNX...>();
  ...
}
```

I've tried to place the `...` in all places I could think of, but i can't get it to compile. Is this not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax, but it looks really weird:

```
template<void(*... Functions)()>
void call_all()
{
    initializer_list<int>{(Functions(), 0)...};
}
```

I'd alias the type, though:

```
template <typename T>
using function_ptr = add_pointer_t<enable_if_t<is_function<T>::value,T>>;

template<function_ptr<void()>... Functions>
void call_all()
{
    initializer_list<int>{(Functions(), 0)...};
}
```

You can also use helper class to do more advanced processing:

```
using fp = function_ptr<string()>;

template<fp First, fp... Others>
struct helper
{
    static void run()
    {
        helper<First>::run();
        helper<Others...>::run();
    }
};

template<fp One>
struct helper<One>
{
    static void run()
    {
        DBG(One());
    }
};

template<fp... Functions>
void run()
{
    helper<Functions...>::run();
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ELmzRIaplIT4MfHQ)

Comment: Great, but how can I pass on the pack to another template (as in my example) without expanding it to actual invocations? I need to call the functions one by one and check their return type before invoking the next one. My actual template has two arguments, the first function and the rest as a pack.